# Process parameters of typical chemical processes

Tags: reference-request, chemical-engineering

I am researching to opportunity of heat recuperation in the chemical industry be means of high temperature heat pumps. However, I am having some trouble with finding suitable applications. I would like to find overviews of processes (e.g. drying, distillation, thermoforming...) that clearly indicate the heat demand of the process with the corresponding temperature at each state. I also need the temperatures and amount of heat released by cooling processes or waste heat sources (the heat pump will transfer this heat to the heat demanding process).

I searched a lot in literature but I found few suitable cases. Does anyone happen to know about certain papers or websites where I can find typical temperature and heat demand/released values of chemical processes ?

A nice example is illustrated in [this figure](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Anton-Kiss/publication/280971212/figure/fig1/AS:689586770546690@1541421706351/Flowsheet-including-key-process-parameters-of-the-classic-bioethanol-separation-by.png)

[image]